# I have some user information in the JSON file. I want to update multiple users' information by using the fs module in nodeJS

Tags: node.js, express

```
[
{
    "id": 1,
    "gender": "male",
    "name": "Harry",
    "contact": "01765489231",
    "address": "park view road, Dhaka",
    "photoUrl": "https://images.unsplash.com/flagged/photo-1570612861542-284f4c12e75f?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8M3x8cGVyc29ufGVufDB8fDB8fA%3D%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60"
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "gender": "male",
    "name": "Xavier",
    "contact": "01648935261",
    "address": "Ring house, Bogra",
    "photoUrl": "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1547425260-76bcadfb4f2c?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8NXx8cGVyc29ufGVufDB8fDB8fA%3D%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60"
},
{
    "id": 3,
    "gender": "female",
    "name": "Anyy",
    "contact": "01554783921",
    "address": "321 street, Comilla",
    "photoUrl": "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1499952127939-9bbf5af6c51c?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8MTJ8fHBlcnNvbnxlbnwwfHwwfHw%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60"
},
{
    "id": 4,
    "gender": "female",
    "name": "Ember",
    "contact": "01812398654",
    "address": "Golden street, Rajshahi",
    "photoUrl": "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1593104547489-5cfb3839a3b5?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8MzB8fHBlcnNvbnxlbnwwfHwwfHw%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60"
},
{
    "id": 5,
    "gender": "male",
    "name": "Gerrad",
    "contact": "01946378254",
    "address": "Ali complex, Khulna",
    "photoUrl": "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1568602471122-7832951cc4c5?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8NDV8fHBlcnNvbnxlbnwwfHwwfHw%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60"
}
```

]

After hitting '/user/bulk-update' route I have to do the following:

- Take an array of user ids and assign it to the body.
- Update multiple users' information in this .json file

Comment: Why don't you use CSV instead of JSON because you need to update whole JSON data every time you update or add new id.

Answer (score 0):

Please don't just ask for code next time.

```
const data = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('myjson.json'));
const {ids} = req.body;
data.forEach(entry => {
    // Do your things here
})
```

Assuming you have a server already set up.